Exercise regarding Hahn-Banach on normed spaces
I am trying to do the following exercise:
Let E be a normed space. Define $E^*$ to be $E^*:=\{f: E \rightarrow \mathbb{K}| f \text{ is continuous and linear }\}$.
Define the family of seminorms $ \mathcal{P}=\{p_f|f \in E^*\}$, where $p_f(x):=|f(x)|$ for $f \in E^*$, $x \in E$.
Show that, if for all $p \in \mathcal{P}$ we have that $p(x)=0$, then $x=0$.
My Approach:
I think that this can be shown using Hahn-Banach. My problem is that I  don't know how to argue.
The version of Hahn-Banach I know is:
Let $E$ be a normed vector space, $U$ a subspace and $f_0:U \rightarrow \mathbb{K}$ linear and continuous. Then there exists a continuous and linear functional $f$ on $X$ such that $||f||=||f_0|| $and $f_{|U}=f_0$.
I tried to consider $span(x)$ as a subspace of $E$ and $\ker(f)$ as a subspace of $E$. But I could not figure out on how to use Hahn-Banach to get the result.

Try setting $U = \mathrm{span}{x}$ and $f_0(\alpha\cdot x) = \alpha$ (assuming $x\neq 0$).

If $x\ne 0$ then let $F=\text{span}\{x\}$, and define $f:F\to\mathbb{K}$ by $f(\lambda x)=\lambda ||x||$ for example. This is clearly a linear functional, and it is immediate that it has norm $1$, so in particular it is bounded. Now extend it using Hahn-Banach, and you get a functional such that $x$ is not in its kernel.
Note that this proof even shows something stronger, that $||x||=\max\{|f(x)|: f\in E^*, ||f||=1\}$.
